# Global Application State in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, aurelia

I'm trying to inject a class to other places in my Aurelia app to share authentication state after login. I'm following this example http://hobbit-on-aurelia.net/appstate/ but it looks like the scope is lost during transitions or they are independent instances. Aurelia's docs says:

> By default, the DI container assumes that everything is a singleton
>   instance;

When I set the router doing `this.userSession.router = router` from app instance, the userSession instance is not updated. `this.loggedUser` is always undefined from outside.

Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qXtSGx

Comment: This is still valid. I'm running Aurelia 1.0.0 and using the article results in the issue stated. Thank goodness I found your question, I've been wondering for about 2 days that this doesnt work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you assume that the user session is a singleton, then that is the problem. In your example the user session is a view template, which is not a singleton. Those get created (in the current implementation, this may change with caching later) whenever you navigate to a view. They also get destroyed whenever you navigate from the view.

What you want is a standalone class that you inject into the constructor of your view model.

```
export class MyViewModel {
   static inject = [UserSession];
   constructor(userSession) {
       this.userSession = userSession;
   }
}
```

This will create a singleton instance, the default behavior, of the service class UserSession. The container will then inject it into the view model when the view is created.

Comment: Ok, this clarifies a lot. I've changed my plunker creating a standalone class. Maybe I'm not getting the whole idea, but it's not working as expected.

Comment: This is a great answer. I've written a blog article on global application state in aurelia here: http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-auth-pt2/