# How do I get the title of the current Router Config Aurelia

Tags: router, aurelia

I want `message` to persist through all pages of my application, and be set after the view-model and view are bounded. Every page I have a very simple template.

```
<template>
    <h1>${message}</h1>
</template>
```

The code behind is empty for each page ('Page1', 'Home', 'Page2').
Here is my app.js

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class App {

    configureRouter(config, router) {
        config.title = 'Pathways';

        config.map([
                { route: ['','home'], name: 'home', moduleId: 'home', nav: true, title:'Home' },
                { route: 'page1', name: 'page1',  moduleId: 'page1',    nav: true, title:'Page1' }

        ]);
        // Create a binding to the router object
        this.router = router;
    }
    attached() {
        this.message = this.router.currentInstruction.config.title;
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I first load the app. `${message}` is blank. Then, when I navigate to page1, the message becomes `Home` !! I thought that maybe the currentInstruction was lagging behind, so I added another page. `Page2` if you will, but it turns out no matter what I do after the first navigation the `message` is always `Home`

So on app initialization `message` is blank, and then upon the first navigation `message` will remain `Home` for the entirety.

My question is, what is the "Aurelia" way to get the title of each page the user is currently on? I would think injecting the router on each page is costly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global Application State in Aurelia](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210597/global-application-state-in-aurelia)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two options:

The first and easiest one is using a getter property that listens to `router.currentInstruction`. For instance:

```
@computedFrom('router.currentInstruction')
get message() {
  if (this.router.currentInstruction !== null)
    return this.router.currentInstruction.config.title;
}
```

Running Example https://gist.run/?id=b01abe2859bc2bea1af0f8d21fc2045f

The second option is using the EventAggregator. For example:

```
attached() {
  this.subscription = this.ea.subscribe('router:navigation:success', () => {
      this.message = this.router.currentInstruction.config.title;
  });
}

detached() {
  this.subscription.dispose(); //remember to always dispose the subscription
}
```

Running example https://gist.run/?id=7d30d4e8d479cc209ca9013e10e91505

They say we should try to avoid the `EventAggregator`. So, I'd go with the first option.

Comment: The first one was beautiful, and elegant. It worked perfectly. Unfortunately, Visual Studio threw syntax errors all over the place, I've gotten in the habit of throwing these lines at the end of my js files. But is their an alternate syntax that would be more Visual Studio friendly?

Comment: The problem is that Visual Studio is not ready to ES6/7 syntax. You should use Visual Studio Code with Aurelia Plugin, which works much better. If this answer solved you problem, please mark it as the correct answer to help other people in the future

Answer (score 1):

You can use `router.currentInstruction.config.title` direct on your `app.html` page and it will be updated every time then router title is changed (it's using [one-way binding](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-basics/1)):

`<h1>title: ${router.currentInstruction.config.title}</h1>`

Best way (thanks comments):
`${router.currentInstruction.config.navModel.title}`

Comment: It's better to use `${router.currentInstruction.config.navModel.title}` because the config.title isn't updated when `routeConfig.navModel.setTitle()` is called.

Comment: Go with above ^---- `${router.currentInstruction.config.navModel.title}`